# Install the Ubuntu sound application in Lubuntu

Tags: sound, lubuntu, menu, settings

what is the name of the sound-control application in Ubuntu 12.10
I want to install it in my Lubuntu 12.10 installation.

Answer (score 0):

You may mean "gnome-sound-applet" ?